# Definite article before specific product names

Tags: articles

I would just like to know: Do we use the definite article (the) before specific names of products like iPhone and iPod? If yes, is there any specific rule as to when and when not to use the article "the" before such names?

Thank you!

Comment: There is no rule; marketing staff may attempt to create them and IP staff may attempt to enforce them, but you can't police what people call things or how. See also *[Why do I want to say “the iPhone” instead of just “iPhone”?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/55351)* and *[Why “the ipad” and not simply ipad?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/106052)*

Comment: Thank you so much for commenting and sharing the sources, choster! So much appreciated! ^_^

Comment: related: https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/33304/when-can-an-article-be-omitted

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, I'd like to offer [some light reading](https://owl.english.purdue.edu/owl/resource/540/01/) on the subject.

iPhones, iPods, and any other product name on its own does not necessitate that one uses the definite article. The rules regarding product names are the same as for other countable nouns.

Examples:

> Give me **the** iPod.

I'm requesting a specific iPod that, it's suggested, you and I are both familiar with.

> Give me **an** iPod.

I'm requesting that you give me one iPod. It doesn't matter which iPod.

> Where is **the** car?

I'm asking where a particular car is. Again, it's assumed you know which car  I'm referring to.

> Where is **a** car?

I'm asking where any car is. If you replace 'car' with 'Mercedes', the meaning doesn't change. Product names aren't special in this regard.

Comment: Thank you for shedding some light on this matter, Coty! I was actually thinking if we could label iPhone as a noncount noun since it refers to a general category of iPhone models. Thanks so much! The information you shared is so much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

This is basically a question about whether something is countable or not.

*iPhones* (and *iPads*) are countable things.  As such, they take articles, such as *an* and *the*.  *Windows 7*  is not countable, notwithstanding the fact that you can buy one or two or an unlimited number of licenses to run the amorphous software.

> This computer comes with *Windows 7* software.

There are times when otherwise uncountable items also take an article (when they have been reduced to an effectively countable thing).

> Do you have the *Windows 7* software (disks/version/files) that came with the computer?

In these cases, the uncountable stuff is a particular set or version that is likely to be understood by the listener.

> *Uncle Ben's* rice is delicious.
>
> The *Uncle Ben's* rice on the shelf is out of date.

Comment: Can we not treat iPhone (and iPad) as an uncountable noun since this refers to a general set of items with quite similar features? For example, there are several models under iPhone (iPhone 4s, 5s, 6, etc.).